# Symmetric power contained in tensor power?

Tags: characteristic-p, positive-characteristic, tensor-powers

Let $V$ be an $R$-module. Traditionally the symmetric algebra $S(V)$ is defined as a quotient of the tensor algebra $T(V)$, by the ideal generated by all $a\otimes b-b\otimes a$.

Can $S^n(V)$ also be viewed as a submodule of $T(V)$?

This is clearly true if $n!$ is invertible in $R$, by mapping $a_1\cdots a_n$ to the symmetrized tensor $1/n!\sum a_{\pi(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes a_{\pi(n)}$. However, I'm interested in a universal construction, valid over all rings.

In particular, without the $1/n!$, the above map would not necessarily be injective: it maps $a^n$ to $n! a^n$ which could be $0$ if the characteristic of $R$ divides $n!$.

Note the related question [MO69940](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69940/can-the-projection-tensor-algebra-symmetric-algebra-be-forced-to-split-in) asking about splitting the natural map $T(V)\to S(V)$. I ask for something weaker, namely just an injective module map that is natural in $V$.

Comment: If you want an injective natural homomorphism $\phi_V : S^n(V) \to T^n(V)$ (not $\to T(V)$), then I'm pretty sure that the answer is "no" whenever $n > 1$. Indeed, let $R$ be an infinite field whose characteristic divides $n$. Let $a \in R$ be the unique constant such that the $1$-dimensional $R$-module $R$ satisfies $\phi_R (1^n) = a \cdot 1^{\otimes n}$ in the $1$-dimensional $R$-module $R^{\otimes n}$. Then, the functoriality of $\phi_V$ shows that every $R$-module $V$ and every $v \in V$ satisfy $\phi_V (v^n) = a \cdot v^{\otimes n}$. Now, let $V = R^2$, and let $x$ and $y$ be ...

Comment: ... the two elements of the standard basis of $V$. Then, the formula we just proved can be applied to $v = x+ty$ for every $t \in R$. We thus obtain $\phi_V ((x+ty)^n) = a \cdot (x+ty)^{\otimes n}$. This holds as a polynomial identity in $t$ (here, we are using the infiniteness of the field $R$); thus, we can extract the coefficients of $t^1$. We thus obtain $\phi_V (nx^{n-1}y) = a \cdot s$, where $s$ is the sum of all pure $n$-tensors which have one tensor factor equal to $y$ and the remaining $n-1$ tensor factors equal to $x$. The left hand side ...

Comment: ... of this equality is $0$ (since $n$ divides $\operatorname{char} R$); thus, the right hand side is $0$, too. Hence, $a = 0$ (since $s \neq 0$). But this yields that the map $\phi_R$ is not injective, a contradiction.

Comment: Note that this leaves the case when $\operatorname{char} R$ is divisible by $n!$ but not by $n$ unanswered. Parts of this case can be solved by extracting other coefficients (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461189/lcm-of-binomial-coefficients-and-related-functions for a useful fact).

Comment: If you really want to send $S^n(V)$ into $T(V)$ instead of $T^n(V)$, the answer is still "no": To see this, it suffices to show that every natural homomorphism $\phi_V : S^n(V) \to T^m(V)$ with $m \neq n$ must be $0$. To prove this, let $R$ be any infinite field, and let $a\in R$ be the unique constant such that the $1$-dimensional $R$-module $R$ satisfies $\phi_R (1^n) = a \cdot 1^m$. Then, the functoriality of $\phi_V$ shows that every $R$-module $V$ and every $v \in V$ satisfy $\phi_V(v^n) = a \cdot v^{\otimes m}$. Now, let $V = R$, and apply this to $v = t$ for a varying $t \in R$.

Comment: Thanks!
I'm a bit puzzled by the fact that $\Lambda^n(V)$ embeds in $T^n(V)$ (even though the map $T(V)\to\Lambda(V)$ does not split) but $S^n(V)$ does not. I guess it's just a fact of life...

Comment: I'm not sure if the embedding $\Lambda^n\left(V\right) \to T^n\left(V\right)$ works generally or just for "nice" (e.g., free) modules $V$. Its definition works fine, but is it always injective?

Comment: Ah, it is not always injective -- I disproved that on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182476/delignes-exterior-power?rq=1 .